# CSS Transition not working with ng-class

Tags: html, css, angularjs, css-transitions

I'm attempting to create a CSS transition when an element receives a certain class. So far the toggle change works (which means that ng-class is working properly), but the animation doesn't happen.

Here's my code:

```
.intro-text{
  height:auto;
  -webkit-transition: height 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: height 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: height 200ms ease-out;
  transition: height 200ms ease-out;
}
.intro-text.hide{
  height:0;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="intro-text" ng-class="{'hide':clicked}">
  <h1>Howdy stranger!</h1>
  <h3>Use the form below to search for an artist and start building your record collection!</h3>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**:  I've narrowed the problem down to bootstrap. If I include the bootstrap.min.css, the animation doesn't work, without it, it works perfectly. Any idea why guys?

**EDIT 2**: Fixed it! The problem is that both .hide and .hidden are classes defined in Bootstrap, so it was overriding my styles, parsing a display:none; before the animation was visible. When changed the class to another name, it got fixed : )

Comment: Seems like it works only if `height` has some numeric value instead of `auto` : http://plnkr.co/edit/ff1O5uSKGtHjdmntVpr1?p=preview

Comment: In my example, doesn't work : SS
http://plnkr.co/edit/JLTJ1BhMTHHmxckGEg5U?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually your issue is not about Angular + ng-class, but about a css3 transition between `height: auto` and `height: 0`.

Here is a SO question about this: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3uxy/

The solution is to do the transition on `max-height` instead of `height`, and to set `max-height` to something big enough.

```
.intro-text{
  max-height:999px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: max-height 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: max-height 200ms ease-out;
  transition: max-height 200ms ease-out;
}
.intro-text.hide{
  max-height:0;
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Y3uxy/

Comment: It gives me the same problem with max-height :/
http://plnkr.co/edit/JLTJ1BhMTHHmxckGEg5U?p=preview

Comment: It isn't on my Linux + Chrome 32. Maybe try to slow down the transition to make it more visible: http://plnkr.co/edit/SjrvDVGwMn9jpHd17z73?p=preview

Comment: Fixed it, the problem is that both .hide and .hidden are classes defined in Bootstrap, so it was overriding it, parsing a display:none; before the animation was visible. When changed the class to another name, it got fixed : )

Comment: @EricMitjans Well done! I think you still have to use `max-height` or `height` with a numerical value. Don't forget to mark the answer accepted if it has helped you ;)